# How to Get Keys and Value In Array Object

Tags: c#

I want get keys and value from Array Object

[image]

Comment: Why do you use ArrayLists?

Comment: support in net 2.0

Comment: Why do you still use .net 2.0? List<T> seems to be there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What type is st[u]?

Comment: Please, paste code instead of using images, it will facilitate the answers

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in st[u])
{ 
   string key = kv.Key;
   string val = kv.Value;
   //Business logic here
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was my fault.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `KeyValuePair` to get the key's and values from array.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in m)
{
 Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

}
```

Comment: You are missing a space.

Comment: @someone But in the OP image there having array list. Not hastable?

Comment: Yes, and that's why I've fixed my comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
    hashtable[1] = "One";
    hashtable[2] = "Two";
    hashtable[13] = "Thirteen";

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hashtable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
You can use hashtable like this
```